# How to configure ADK/virtual devices for Meteor/CORDOVA-PREVIEW@5?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

**Question:** How can I configure the ADK automatically installed through `meteor add-platform android`? The command proposed in the [documenting Hackpad](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Getting-Started-With-Cordova-Z5n6zkVB1xq) (`meteor configure-android`) doesn't exist.

**Background:** I ran everything as described in the hackpad, but when I run `meteor run android --verbose` I get (after a lot of output) this:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to virtual
Waiting for emulator...
PANIC: Could not open: virtual
```

*Secondary question: Where can I file this as a bug?*

Comment: in a newer release (that is not ready yet) you can type `meteor configure-android`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As @imslavko pointed out, the feature wasn't yet added, but for completeness I'll add this as an answer with the relevant source.*

As stated in the [Meteor Cordova Phonegap integration](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#configuring-android-virtual-devices):

> Meteor tries to set up a virtual device for you, but it's possible that it will be 
>   incorrect or misconfigured for your machine. You can open the Android configuration tool 
>   from Meteor's environment by calling the following command:
>
> `meteor configure-android`

Answer (score 2):

Try to start the android emulator first, and then run the meteor command.

Here's some steps if you (or someone else) need it:

Create/configure an android virtual device (AVD) first with:

```
> android avd
```

In my case, I created a AVD with the name *meteor* and CPU: ARM (armeabi-v7a).
If you don't have that CPU option, you can install the ARM System Image with the Android SDK Manager running:

```
> android
```

Start the emulator with the AVD we just created:

```
> emulator -avd meteor
```

when finished loading the emulator run:

```
> meteor run android --verbose
```

Comment: Did you let Meteor install the ADK for you or did you install it by hand? I chose the first option, and I believe it wasn't added to `PATH`, because running `android avd` gets as far as `android: command not found`. (Running Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: I let Meteor install it, but I already had the android on my ubuntu. :(

Comment: Thanks for this, I spent lots of time today to try and figure out exactly this sequence of commands!